# How to match the text file against multiple regex patterns and count the number of occurences of these patterns?

Tags: java, regex, count

I want to find and count all the occurrences of the words unit, device, method, module in every line of the text file separately. That's what I've done, but I don't know how to use multiple patterns and how to count the occurrence of every word in the line separately? Now it counts only occurrences of all words together for every line. Thank you in advance!

```
private void countPaterns() throws IOException {

    Pattern nom = Pattern.compile("unit|device|method|module|material|process|system");

    String str = null;      

    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:/test/test1.txt")); 

    while ((str = r.readLine()) != null) {
        Matcher matcher = nom.matcher(str);

        int countnomen = 0;
        while (matcher.find()) {
            countnomen++;
        }

        //intList.add(countnomen);
        System.out.println(countnomen + " davon ist das Wort System");
    }
    r.close();
    //return intList;
}
```

Comment: Please add useful tags, such as what language you're using. "count", "matcher", and "find-occurences" are not useful for this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better to use a word boundary and use a map to keep counts of each matched keyword.

```
Pattern nom = Pattern.compile("\\b(unit|device|method|module|material|process|system)\\b");

String str = null;
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:/test/test1.txt"));
Map<String, Integer> counts = new HashMap<>();

while ((str = r.readLine()) != null) {
    Matcher matcher = nom.matcher(str);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        String key = matcher.group(1);
        int c = 0;
        if (counts.containsKey(key))
            c = counts.get(key);
        counts.put(key, c+1)
    }
}
r.close();

System.out.println(counts);
```

Comment: Thanks! it works this way very good, but the only problem that I get the number of occurrences for the whole txt file. But  I need to get this number for every new line of the text separately. Before your change it has worked for every line

Comment: If you want count per line then add `counts.clear()` after `Matcher matcher = nom.matcher(str);` line and make sure to print it inside the outer `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Java 9 (and above) solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> expressions = List.of("(good)", "(bad)");
    String phrase = " good  bad     bad good   good bad bad bad";

    for (String regex : expressions) {
        Pattern gPattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = gPattern.matcher(phrase);
        long count = matcher.results().count();
        System.out.println("Pattern \"" + regex + "\" appears " + count + (count == 1 ? " time" : " times"));
    }
}
```

Outputs

```
Pattern "(good)" appears 3 times
Pattern "(bad)" appears 5 times
```